# How to filter a domain view with a function? In odoo 9

Tags: filter, odoo, odoo-9

I want to filter a domain with a function instead of a variable in order to show only some registers in the view. 
I have done this:

```py
class SaleOrderExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['sale.order']

    @api.multi
    def custom_funct_date(self):
        my_date = ... (some stuff)
        return my_date
```

Then, in the view, I have filtered the domain:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record id='action_menu_custom_date' model='ir.actions.act_window'>
      <field name="name">This is a test</field>
      <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
      <field name="view_type">form</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
      <field name="domain">[('date_order','>=',custom_funct_date)]</field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

But this is giving me an error:

```
ValueError: "name 'custom_funct_date' is not defined" while evaluating
u"[('date_order','>=',custom_funct_date)]"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instead of using  ir.actions.act_window use ir.actions.server using server action
you can call your function and return a action to open your model using your computed
domain.

```xml
    <record id="action_menu_custom_dat" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Your Action</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">action = self.custom_funct_date(cr, uid, context=context)</field>
        <field eval="True" name="condition"/>
    </record>
```

and in your model change the method to:

```py
     def custom_funct_date(self, cr, uid, context=None):
            # print "make sure that this action is called from th server action "
            # compute you date
            my_date = ... (some stuff)
            tree_id = self.env.ref("modul_name.view_tree_id")
            form_id = self.env.ref("modul_name.view_form_id")
            return {
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'name': 'This is a test',
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'tree,form',
                'res_model': 'sale.order',
                'domain': [('date_order','>=',my_date)],
                # if you don't want to specify form for example
                # (False, 'form') just pass False 
                'views': [(tree_id.id, 'tree'), (form_id.id, 'form')],
                'target': 'current',
                'context': context,
            }
```

Comment: That works but now the problem is that I had customized the form view and the tree view (adding more fields and editing some labels) and now it is loading the standard sale.order model without any modification.

I never used the ir.actions.server model and I don't know how to put additional fields or modify the current ones. It is possible to do this?

Comment: In the return statement you can specify the ids of the views. Think 'views': [('tree',self.env.ref('modulename. Idtree')),(,)]  Google it you will find example i'm using my phone i will help you when i grt home but at least up vote my friend

Comment: Okay, tomorrow I will continue checking. I just have voted you up :) When I had checked this, I will vote your answer as a solution

Comment: hope this help , check my edit ref() return an object this is way i did obj.id in ref you should pass the name of the folder and the id of the view ok

Comment: That's it! Marked as a solution :)

Only for curiosity, can you add more information to the answer of @jo541 with the computed_field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the domain, you need to pass a field not a name of a function.

To do this you can create a compute field. Assign your method to the computed field.

After you specified a search attribute for you compute field.

Odoo Example:

```py
upper_name = field.Char(compute='_compute_upper', search='_search_upper')

def _search_upper(self, operator, value):
    if operator == 'like':
        operator = 'ilike'
    return [('name', operator, value)]
```

For you case:

```py
class SaleOrderExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['sale.order']

    your_date = fields.Datetime(string="Computed date", compute="compute_your_date", search="_search_date")

    @api.depends('date')
    def compute_your_date(self):
        my_date = ... (some stuff)
        return my_date


    def _search_date(self, operator, value):
        return [('date', operator, value)]
```

Edit:

Your xml code must be like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record id='action_menu_custom_date' model='ir.actions.act_window'>
      <field name="name">This is a test</field>
      <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
      <field name="view_type">form</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
      <field name="domain">[('date_order','>=',your_date)]</field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: It gives me KeyError: 'date'

Comment: Anyway, if i delete the part of "api.depends", it gives me that error: ValueError: "name 'your_date' is not defined" while evaluating
u"[('date_order','>=', your_date)]"

Comment: this is not going to work because your_date here is Treated as  a variable not a field and this way you get the error is not defined because there is no variable your_date when odoo is building the domain.

Comment: @CherifOdoo and what is the correct sintax to put a computed field in the right side of the domain filter?

Answer (score 0):

Many time since the last answer, but it can be usefull to other ones.

I'd have similar problem with res.partner inherited view and this is how I resolved it. In this case, I need the user to be the partner who accesses their data or the admin to show the partner's data in the notebook section.

Model:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

 @api.multi
    def _get_domain(self):
    # Remember that self returns a recordset, so we need to iterate over that
    # dominio (domain in english) -boolean- store if the user is the partner or the admin
        for rec in self:
            rec.dominio =  True if self.id == self.env.user.partner_id.id or self.env.user.has_group('cnae.group_cnae_manager') else False

    dominio = fields.Boolean(string='Dominio', compute=_get_domain)
```

XML:

```
... ir.ui.view header record stuff ...

<!--  Hide notebook to other users -->
<xpath expr="//notebook" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible':[('dominio','=',False)]}</attribute>
</xpath>
```